# Event Handler for a non-selectable menu item

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a form with Material UI React. This form will log a set for an exercise to my database. For one of the inputs, users select the name of the exercise they want to log from a list of Material UI Menu Item components. I also want to give the user the option to add an exercise to the list if it's not included (new exercise they haven't done before). I added the disabled attribute and tried to use onClick event listener like so:

```
<TextField
  id="exerciseName"
  label="Exercise Name"
  select
>
  <MenuItem disabled onClick={() => console.log("Add Exercise Clicked")}>
    Add Exercise
  </MenuItem>

  {exercises &&
    exercises.map((exercise) => (
      <MenuItem key={exercise.id} value={exercise.exerciseName}>
        {exercise.exerciseName}
      </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

After trying this, I realised that event handlers can not be triggered on disabled elements. Is there a way in which I can achieve a disabled state for the add exercise menu item, so that it can't be selected as a value for the input, but runs an onClick handler when triggered?

Answer (score 0):

**For accessibility**, a disabled element has those events disabled. Try to set a style similar to your disabled item.